# Adding parent_id attribute value in model

Tags: collection, model, eav, resource-model

I have created a module and EAV tables for that. Module's tables are very similar to `customer_Address` entity and i have defined Attribute *AttrA*, *AttrB* and *AttrC* for this table.

So table structure is very similar to as follows:

```
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type                 | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| entity_id        | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| entity_type_id   | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| attribute_set_id | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| increment_id     | varchar(50)          | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| parent_id        | int(10) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL                |                |
| created_at       | timestamp            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at       | timestamp            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| is_active        | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 1                   |                |
+------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

and *AttrA, AttrB and AttrC* values are stored in tables with respective data type.

Now using the basic syntax, I am able to add value of attributes *AttrA, AttrB and AttrC*. Which is:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$model->setAttrA('ValA')->setAttrB('ValB')->setAttrC('ValC');
```

doing this correctly sets the values of *AttrA, AttrB and AttrC* but value of `parent_id` in `customer_entity` sets to `NULL` by default.

Here I want to be able to set the `parent_id` to some other value.

For this i tried suggestion given in different post using `setParentId(<parent-id-value>)`. Which is not working in my case. Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: This should do. Did you clean the cache? Zend_Db caches the table structure to know what can be written to the table - so rm -rf on the directory helps

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I have disabled cache in my Magento setup.

Comment: You can't disable the Zend_Db cache.

Answer (score 1):

Even if `parent_id` is a column in the main table, you still need it as an attribute in the `eav_attribute` table.
Just create one attribute called `parent_id` (the same as the column) with the `backend_type` "static".

This is how it works for the `sku` attribute for products.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try 
`$model->setData('parent_id', $value);`
and as a personal opinion i would double/triple check you are saving the object correctly.

Comment: Tried this as well. Also, printed $model->getData() before $model->save(). Which returns Array
(
    [parent_id] => 22
    [name] => test name
) Is this how it should look?

Comment: Yes, dump the var again to see how does it looks after save() and check the db to see if info is stored.